# puppet concat::fragment not inserting content in vhost

Tags: apache2, puppet, concatenation, vhosts

So I have a vhost config in my puppet manifest file

```
apache::vhost { 'site.dev':
    port => '80',
    docroot => '/home/vagrant/projects/Personal/php/site/public',
    serveradmin => 'admin@admin.dev',
    options => ['Indexes','FollowSymLinks','MultiViews'],
    setenv => ["APP_ENV dev"],
    override => ['All'],
}
```

Now I want to add these options

```
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP Off
```

I googled and found that concat::fragment might just be what I need, so I tried the following:

```
concat::fragment { "site.dev-static":
      target  => '25-site.dev.conf',
      order   => '01',
      content => '
        EnableSendfile Off
        EnableMMAP Off
      ',
}
```

**NOTE**
In the target I have also tried with the full path: /etc/apache2/sites-available/25-site.dev.conf (with same results)

When I do vagrant provision I get this:

```
-- snip --
==> acs_dev: Warning: Scope(Concat::Fragment[Listen 80]): The $ensure parameter to concat::fragment is deprecated and has no effect.
-- snip --
```

I assume this worked fine but when I go to the vhos file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/25-site.dev.conf the **EnableSendfile** and **EnableMMAP**  are not there.

I am using version 2.0.0 of puppetlabs concat module.

What do I need to do to make this work??

**UPDATE**

Apparently I could have just used

```
custom_fragment
```

In the vhost code. Don't know why this doesn't appear first in the module documentation.

Comment: Wait, is `puppetlabs-apache` supposed to mix with `puppetlabs-concat` this way? You should carefully review the README (and perhaps the code) of your version of the `apache` module.

Comment: I have seen similar code here: https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/140374/puppet-apache--vhost-with-custom-configu If you don't know about this please refrain from commenting.

Comment: Also there if you search in the puppetlabs-apache documentation you will see a similar example https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom fragments in the vhost code like so:

```
apache::vhost { 'foo':
  port              => '80',
  ip                => '127.0.0.1',
  add_listen        => false,
  proxy_pass        => [
    {
      'path' => '/',
      'url' => "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
      'reverse_urls' => "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    },
  ],
  docroot           => '/var/www/html',
  custom_fragment   => '# Fragment content',
}
```

I also find that using the `template` function makes it easier to manage the content if it's a long fragment:

```
custom_fragment   => template('apache_profile/etc/httpd/apache_custom_fragment.erb'),
```

The `custom_fragment` parameter is documented in the [README.md](http://The%20%60custom_fragment%60%20parameter%20is%20documented%20in%20the%20[https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#custom_fragment-1][1]%20and%20there's%20an%20example%20given.)

Comment: Thanks that was what I found out and posted as an update to the question